# Calcular o ponto mais perto e traçar rota no Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, rotas

Eai, bom,vou tentar ser breve e claro ao mesmo tempo, gostaria de saber como posso calcular qual ponto está mais perto da minha localização, tenho markers por todo o mapa ja, e tenho minha localização, o unico problema é o calculo para ver qual é a rota mais próxima.
Acho que é só isso, qualquer coisa só pedirem que disponibilizo parte do código e tudo mais. Abraço!

Comment: Tem, mas não existe maneira eficiente, pois isso é um problema NP completo.

Answer (score 1):

Trustow, a documentação da Api do Google é bem rica. Verifique no link abaixo, acredito que tem tudo que você precisa.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters

Você consegue retornar um Json fazendo um requisição HTTPS ou HTTP.